# Trying to Create a Dashboard for Data in Python

Tags: python

I am currently experiencing an error when attempting to run a template for a dashboard.

I am looking to see if line 7, 29 & 141 are simply formatting issues.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1648\3613514742.py in <module>
      5     sidebar=[pn.pane.Markdown("# CO2 Emissions and Climate Change"), 
      6              pn.pane.Markdown("#### Carbon dioxide emissions are the primary driver of global climate change. It’s widely recognised that to avoid the worst impacts of climate change, the world needs to urgently reduce emissions. But, how this responsibility is shared between regions, countries, and individuals has been an endless point of contention in international discussions."),
----> 7              pn.pane.PNG('climate_day.png', sizing_mode='scale_both'),
      8              pn.pane.Markdown("## Settings"),
      9              year_slider],

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\image.py in __init__(self, object, **params)
     27         if isinstance(object, PurePath):
     28             object = str(object)
---> 29         super().__init__(object=object, **params)
     30 
     31     def _type_error(self, object):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\base.py in __init__(self, object, **params)
    139         applies = self.applies(object, **(params if self._applies_kw else {}))
    140         if (isinstance(applies, bool) and not applies) and object is not None :
--> 141             self._type_error(object)
    142 
    143         super().__init__(object=object, **params)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\image.py in _type_error(self, object)
     31     def _type_error(self, object):
     32         if isinstance(object, str):
---> 33             raise ValueError("%s pane cannot parse string that is not a filename "
     34                              "or URL." % type(self).__name__)
     35         super()._type_error(object)

ValueError: PNG pane cannot parse string that is not a filename or URL.
```

Overall code below

```
template = pn.template.FastListTemplate(
    title='World CO2 emission dashboard', 
    sidebar=[pn.pane.Markdown("# CO2 Emissions and Climate Change"), 
             pn.pane.Markdown("#### Carbon dioxide emissions are the primary driver of global climate change. It’s widely recognised that to avoid the worst impacts of climate change, the world needs to urgently reduce emissions. But, how this responsibility is shared between regions, countries, and individuals has been an endless point of contention in international discussions."), 
             pn.pane.PNG('climate_day.png', sizing_mode='scale_both'),
             pn.pane.Markdown("## Settings"),   
             year_slider],
    main=[pn.Row(pn.Column(yaxis_co2, 
                           co2_plot.panel(width=700), margin=(0,25)), 
                 co2_table.panel(width=500)), 
          pn.Row(pn.Column(co2_vs_gdp_scatterplot.panel(width=600), margin=(0,25)), 
                 pn.Column(yaxis_co2_source, co2_source_bar_plot.panel(width=600)))],
    accent_base_color="#88d8b0",
    header_background="#88d8b0",
)
# template.show()
template.servable();
```

I was attempting to create a dashboard layout using a template provided.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have the file 'climate_day.png', try using this URL https://github.com/thu-vu92/python-dashboard-panel/blob/main/climate_day.png

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34813134)